# Isomorphism between $G$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{*}$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $\{G_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a family of additive groups with $G_{1}=\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $G_{n}=\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\geq 2$
$$G=\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}}G_{n}$$

I want to prove that $G\cong \mathbb{Q}^{*}$

I can't find the correct function, can you give me a hint?
 I tried :

$$(g_{1},g_{2},...)\longrightarrow -1^{g_{1}}\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{g_{n}}{10^{n-2}} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it: $P$ the set of all prime numbers.

$$\phi(g_{1},g_{2}, ...)= -1^{g_{1}}\prod _{n\geq1} p^{g_{n}}_{n}$$

with $p_{n}\in P$. Since $g_{n}$ allows negative numbres, and all rationals are $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and$ b\neq0$. It's clear is one to one.
Then: $g,h \in G$

$$\phi(g+h)=\phi(g_{1}+h_{1},g_{2}+h_{2}, ...)=-1^{g_{1}+h_{1}}\prod _{n\geq1} p^{g_{n}+h_{n}}_{n}=(-1^{g_{1}})(-1^{h_{1}})\prod _{n\geq1} p^{g_{n}}_{n}p^{h_{n}}_{n}=\phi(g)\phi(h)$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Think of the $G_n$'s for $n>1$ as being indexed by the prime numbers, and use prime factorization.

Comment: And remember that all but finitely many $g_i$ are $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I posted my answer below.